# Getting throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'Function', value);

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using socket.io and getting this error:

```
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'Function', value);
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
```

I am making a controller for the callbacks on the socket, this is how it looks:

```
const { onDisconnect } = require('./app/controllers/socket');

/*
...
*/

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('disconnect', onDisconnect(socket));
});
```

I get the error right on the "onDisconect" function. However if I declare the function like this, it works:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`${socket.id} disconnected`);
    });
});
```

I have the "onDisconect" function on another script, which contains this:

```
const onDisconnect = (socket) => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} disconnected`);
}

module.exports = { onDisconnect };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're calling `onDisconnect()`, which returns `undefined`, which is not a function. You have two options:

1. Simply change `socket.on("disconnect", onDisconnect(socket))` to `socket.on("disconnect", onDisconnect)`
2. Return a function in `onDisconnect`:

```js
function onDisconnect(socket) {
  return () => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} disconnected`);
  };
}
```

Comment: Oh I see.
I was calling the function instead of sending it to the listener. It was expecting a value.
Its clear now. 
Thank you.

Comment: @JorgeIsaacVizcaínoMartínez no problem. If this answered your question would you kindly select it as the answer?